# R-function which makes use of parallel programming (pdredge, R-package MuMIn) is very slow within another function

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing

I am using the function pdredge (i.e. model averaging using parallel computing) from package MuMIn succesfully. Utilizing more cores speeds up the task as expected. However, when I execute the code from within another function, the speed slows down substantially, i.e. 5-10 times. That is, "code" works fine, but "function(code)" does not. In fact, not using parallelisation is even faster then. (I experience the same problem when calling pdredge from within "boot" [bootstrapping]) The question is: how can pdredge be used within another function such that there are gains in speed as one would expect? Does anyone have an idea? I tried several things, but to no avail...

I have created a small reproducible example:

```
library(MuMIn)
library(parallel)
set.seed(24121980)

# 1) pdredge within a function
cores<-4
clusterType <- if(length(find.package("snow", quiet = TRUE))) "SOCK" else "PSOCK"
clust <- try(makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", cores), type = clusterType))

test<- function(myclust=clust){
p1 <- p2 <- p3 <- p4 <- p5 <- p6 <- rnorm(10000) # just for simplicity
mu    <- - 3*p1 - 0.6*p2 - 1.25*p4 +  1.85*p6 
y <- rnorm(10000, mu, 3)
dataex <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6))
clusterExport(myclust, c("dataex"), envir=environment())
mymodel <- lm(y~.,data=dataex,na.action=na.fail)
mymo <- pdredge(mymodel, cluster=myclust)
}

ptm1 <-  proc.time()
test(myclust=clust)
ptm2 <-  proc.time()
mytime1 <- round((((ptm2-ptm1)/60))[1],digits=4)

stopCluster(clust)

# 2) pdredge not within a fucntion

cores<-4
clusterType <- if(length(find.package("snow", quiet = TRUE))) "SOCK" else "PSOCK"
clust <- try(makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", cores), type = clusterType))
myclust<-clust

ptm3 <-  proc.time()
p1 <- p2 <- p3 <- p4 <- p5 <- p6 <- rnorm(10000)  # just for simplicity
mu    <- - 3*p1 - 0.6*p2 - 1.25*p4 +  1.85*p6 
y <- rnorm(10000, mu, 3)
dataex <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6))
clusterExport(myclust, c("dataex"), envir=environment())
mymodel <- lm(y~.,data=dataex,na.action=na.fail)
mymo <- pdredge(mymodel, cluster=myclust)
ptm4 <-  proc.time()

mytime2 <- round((((ptm4-ptm3)/60))[1],digits=4)
stopCluster(clust)

# 1) parallel, 4 cores, in function
mytime1
# 0.0125 

# 2) parallel, 4 cores, no function
mytime2    
# 0.001
```

Comment: I didn't experience such a big difference. I got 3.2s for the first run and 1.7s for the second.

Comment: Thanks. I think the magnitude of difference depends on the computer and the number of available cores. On my machine it makes a 10-times difference for the simple example code. No matter how long the difference is, the important point here is that for code "1)" the slowdown is always so big that the calculation time is longer for using parallelisation versus not using parallelisation at all, which shouldn't be the case.....